# how identify geographical location and redirect in particular page with php?

Tags: php

I would like to ask, how I can identify geographical location and redirect the user in their geographic web page using php. 
I know the redirection is like.

`<?php

header('Location: mypage.php');

?>`

I appreciate for your help

Comment: This might get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320674/get-a-users-state-with-geolocation

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

if (navigator.geolocation) { 

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {  

        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    if (results[1]) {
    alert(results[7].formatted_address);
    }
  } else {
    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
  }
});
      });
      } else {
        alert("Geolocation services are not supported by your browser.");
} 

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Using this you can get Coordinates of place and then using Google API you can have country code and accordingly you can send user to particular page